# Can't get the scrollTo jQuery effect to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems implementing the **One Page Nav** and **scrollTo** jQuery plugins (Seems I need more reputation to post the links, so I hope you know which plugins I'm referring to). I'm a complete beginner to Javascript and I just want the links of my navigation bar to have a scrolling effect [as seen here](http://www.catalytic-design.com/#home).

I've pasted the entire code of my html page below as I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. For now I've left in the ready functions from both plugins (although I have tried with only one - and also tried attaching it to 'div#nav', '#navbar', etc.).

```
    <html>

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>deepeedesigns - Portfolio site of Web Designer Dan Pierce</title>

        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href=""><!--favicon-->

        <meta name="description" content=""><!--description that appears under Google listing-->

       <meta name="keywords" content="">

       <meta name="robots" content="">

       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">

       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
       <script src="js/jquery.nav.js"></script>

   </head>

    <body>

    <div id="header">

        <div class="container">

            <div id="navbar">

                <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png"></div>

                    <ul id="nav">
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>

            </div><!--navbar-->  

        </div><!--container-->

    </div><!--header-->

    <div id="home">

        <div class="background">

            <div class="container">


            </div><!--container-->

        </div><!--background-->

    </div><!--home-->

    <div id="about">

        <div class="background">

            <div class="container">


            </div><!--container-->

        </div><!--background-->

    </div><!--about-->

    <div id="portfolio">

        <div class="background">

            <div class="container">


            </div><!--container-->

        </div><!--background-->

    </div><!--portfolio-->

    <div id="contact">

        <div class="background">

            <div class="container">


            </div><!--container-->

        </div><!--background-->

    </div><!--contact-->

    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav').onePageNav();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav').$scrollTo();
});

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You missed script tag .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use `Jquery` to scroll top. You can use it on `window` object

```
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

But if you want to animate or want to perform scroll on specific element, then you can use `jquery`

```
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

In your code, you have to write your javascript code inside `<script></script>` tag.
There is an spelling mistake of `scrollTo` instead of `$scrollTo`

**Back To Top Link**

*HTML*

```
 <a class="btn-go-top" href="javascript:window.scrollTo(0,0);">Go to top</a>
```

*CSS*

```
.btn-go-top {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I was planning on having a 'back to top' button at the end of each page. Could you please show me how 'window' would be attached to a link?

Comment: Updated my answer for go to top.

Comment: You have to check the tick if the answer helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your opening `<script>` and closing `</script>` tag for the jQuery?

**Update**:

Why declare `$(document).ready` twice?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#nav').onePageNav();
      $('#nav').scrollTo();
    });
```

Comment: So this declaration also needs to go into a script tag? I've only seen it written as above, and thought the $ was sufficient!